# Simple problem in multiple checkbox selection with executable example. Is there automatic way to recognize the plurality multiple selected checkboxes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, checkbox

Is there an automatic way to recognize the plurality of multiple selected checkboxes? I don't want to manually create multiple selection combinations. I would like to get that:

- 1/3 checkbox: if I select the first or third box individually, I get the print "ok" in the text box
- 2/3 checkbox: if I select the first and third at the same time, I get the print "ok" in the text box. But only one "ok" printed, and not two ok as "ok ok" (so two checkboxes correspond to one ok)
- I don't want to print the second checkbox in the textbox, because I intentionally wrote an error on it.

The problem is this function. Probably AND (or OR) is not what I need, I guess, I don't know:

```
def aaa():
    if Checkbutton1.get() and Checkbutton2.get() and Checkbutton3.get():
        textbox.insert("end", "Ok")

#I also tried to write: if Button1_func() and Button2_func() and Button3_func():
```

I guess the solution is to create other conditions for each type of multiple selection case, but I think there is a more automatic and better way without creating selection cases with conditions, because I will have to add dozens of other checkboxes and the situation would get complicated.

IMPORTANT: Please do not make sarcasm about True and False, because 5 + 3 = 8 is just a simple example to understand the logic of the checkboxes to which I will have to apply other different code. Leave the return True and False as is, without changing the functions.

Can anyone possibly help me by showing me the correct code? Thank you

```
import sqlite3
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.messagebox
from tkinter import messagebox

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("600x600")
root.configure(bg='white')

Checkbutton1 = IntVar()
Checkbutton2 = IntVar()
Checkbutton3 = IntVar()

#CHECKBOX'S FUNCTIONS
def Button1_func():
    if 5 + 3 == 8:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def Button2_func():
    if 5 + 3 == 7:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def Button3_func():
    if 5 + 3 == 8:
        return True
    else:
        return False

#CHECKBOX
Button1 = Checkbutton(root, text = "Checkbox 1", variable = Checkbutton1, onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height = 1,
                      bg="white", foreground='black', activebackground="white", command=Button1_func)
Button1.place(x=10, y=36)

Button2 = Checkbutton(root, text = "Checkbox 2", variable = Checkbutton2, onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height = 1,
                      bg="white", foreground='black', activebackground="white", command=Button2_func)
Button2.place(x=10, y=66)

Button3 = Checkbutton(root, text = "Checkbox 3", variable = Checkbutton3, onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height = 1,
                      bg="white", foreground='black', activebackground="white", command=Button3_func)
Button3.place(x=10, y=146)

#BUTTON FUNCTION
def aaa():
    if Checkbutton1.get() and Checkbutton2.get() and Checkbutton3.get():
        textbox.insert("end", "Ok")

    #I also tried to write: if Button1_func () and Button2_func () and Button3_func ():

#TEXTOBOX
textbox = tk.Text(root, width=33, height=10, font=('helvetic', 12))
textbox.place(x=30, y=220)

#BUTTON
button = tk.Button(root, text="Ok", command= lambda: [aaa()])
button.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

UPDATE
In the code there is also this with which I save and load the checkboxes:

```
chk_lst = []
chk_lst.extend([Checkbutton1,Checkbutton2, Checkbutton3])
```

Comment: No, there isn't an automatic way to do it. Also note that you must *call* the `get` method to retrieve the checkbutton's current value. i.e. `Checkbutton1.get()`

Comment: Also note that the return value of the `command=` function is ignored — it is simply something that gets called whenever the state of `Checkbutton` is changed.

Comment: @martineau I forgot to add () to get, but that's not the main problem. If there isn't something automatic, how can I fix it? It is impossible to create combinations of multiple selections per checkbox, in the sense that it is very difficult to manage. I'll have to add dozens of other checkboxes, so it's hard to manage all the combinations. Can you help me somehow please? I would very much appreciate your kind help. Thank you

Comment: I may be able to help. By "plurality of multiple selected checkboxes" do you mean, in this case, simply 2 or more of them checked (or something else)?

Comment: Will you be defining a unique function for each checkbox?

Comment: @martineau Yes, two or more, based on True or False, but without creating combinations. I would like to add another 20 or 30 checkboxes, so it would be very difficult and tiring to create so many combinations. So I would need both for only 1 selected checkbox, and for 2 or more. You are very kind. I hope you or jezza_99 can help me. Thank you

Comment: How does whether a `Checkbutton` has been checked or not relate to the return value of each of your `ButtonX_func()` functions (and the expressions like `5 + 3 == 7` inside them)?

Comment: @martineau In what sense? I did not understand the question sorry

Comment: Are you wanting the `Checkbutton` to be ticked or not depending on whether the function associated with it returns `True` or `False` respectively?

Comment: @jezza_99  No, I don't want this. Thank you :)

Comment: The user can click on a `Checkbutton` to check or uncheck it. How does that relate to the True or False values you have your check button functions returning?

Comment: Do you want it so that when you press the button, all of the functions for the ticked checkboxes are run and if they all return `True` you print `Ok`?

Comment: @martineau My intention is that if you select a checkbox it starts the math operation in the relevant checkbox function. If the result of the operation is correct (True), then "ok" is printed in the textbox. If the result of the operation is incorrect (False) then nothing is printed in the textbox. But if I select two checkboxes (1 and 3) with the correct result True, then "ok" is printed in the textbox (only one ok, not "ok ok"). I hope you can help me. Thank you

Comment: @jezza_99 Yes, right. While if only one function of the three is False (therefore the second checkbox), even selecting all the three checkboxes, then nothing will be printed, because there is checkbox 2 which is False. Instead, for example, if I select only checkbox 1 and 2 which are both true, "ok" will be printed in the textbox. However, consider that this is an example and that I will insert another 20 checkboxes with the same logic.

Comment: Does each checkbox point to a unique function? If so, you will need to define it for each of your 20 checkboxes

Comment: @jezza_99 Yes, each checkbox has its own function

Comment: @DragomirCro I believe I have answered your question now. You should [edit] your question to include the clarifications found in these comments

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242088/discussion-between-jezza-99-and-dragomir-cro).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a *set* to store the function references based on the state of those checkbuttons. Then inside `aaa()` executes all the functions in the *set* and determine whether to put OK into the text box or not:

```
def clicked(flag, func):
    if flag:
        funclist.add(func)
    else:
        funclist.remove(func)

funclist = set()

#CHECKBOX
Button1 = tk.Checkbutton(root, text = "Checkbox 1", variable = Checkbutton1, onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height = 1,
                         bg="white", foreground='black', activebackground="white",
                         command=lambda: clicked(Checkbutton1.get(), Button1_func))
Button1.place(x=10, y=36)

Button2 = tk.Checkbutton(root, text = "Checkbox 2", variable = Checkbutton2, onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height = 1,
                         bg="white", foreground='black', activebackground="white",
                         command=lambda: clicked(Checkbutton2.get(), Button2_func))
Button2.place(x=10, y=66)

Button3 = tk.Checkbutton(root, text = "Checkbox 3", variable = Checkbutton3, onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height = 1,
                         bg="white", foreground='black', activebackground="white",
                         command=lambda: clicked(Checkbutton3.get(), Button3_func))
Button3.place(x=10, y=146)

#BUTTON FUNCTION
def aaa():
    # if need to clear the text box, uncomment below line
    #textbox.delete("1.0", "end")
    if funclist and all(func() for func in funclist):
        textbox.insert("end", "Ok")
```

Comment: Thanks, now I try your code. give me some minutes

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm looking for. But there is something that does not convince me, can I ask you for a small change to your code please?Let me explain: when I open the window,the checkboxes are shown already selected or deselected because they are saved and loaded into the database based on 0 or 1. In the question I did not write it because I already have the working code of saving and loading,so it is not a problem, but I notice that from your code maybe loading and saving (adding my code later) is not possible. I am referring to funclist.add (func).Or am I wrong? Thank you

Comment: My solution is based on provided information. If you have other requirement, suggest to post another question.

Comment: It is not a different request. Basically the selection or deselection of my checkboxes are saved and loaded with chk_lst = [] and chk_lst.extend ([Checkbutton1, Checkbutton2, Checkbutton3]). Is it possible to change your code using these? Now I also add them to the question. Thank you

Comment: No it is new request to your original question.

Comment: OK then. Now I vote your question because you helped me solve the problem, but I open a similar one in which I add another request. Can you help me with the other question? Thank you

Comment: I brought back your code and I made your name. Can you help me please? Thank you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71151908/apply-multiple-selection-functions-to-checkboxes-they-are-saved-and-loaded-from

Answer (score 0):

**Edited for clarified question**

Because each `Checkbutton` has a unique function associated with it, you will need to define these all manually. For now, I've substituted functions to stand in.

You don't actually need to pass the functions to your checkbuttons, because they are only evaluated when you click your `Button`. Instead, you can change `aaa` so that it creates a list of the function results for the ticked `Checkbuttons`. If any of these return `False`, don't print "OK". But if they all return `True`, print "OK"

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("600x600")

# How many checkboxes you want
buttons = 5
button_eval = [0 for i in range(buttons)]

# If your functions are unique for each checkbox, you will need to define them here
def foo():
    return True
def bar():
    return False
my_functions = [foo, bar, foo, bar, foo] # You need to have 5 functions in this case for this to work

# Creating variables, buttons etc
x = [10, 10, 10, 10, 10]
y = [36, 66, 96, 126, 156]
checkbuttons_vars = [tk.IntVar() for _ in range(buttons)]
checkbuttons = [tk.Checkbutton(root, text=f"Checkbox {i+1}", variable=checkbuttons_vars[i], onvalue=1, offvalue=0) for i in range(buttons)]
for i, box in enumerate(checkbuttons):
    box.place(x=x[i],y=y[i])

#BUTTON FUNCTION
def aaa():
    function_results = [function() for i, function in enumerate(my_functions) if checkbuttons_vars[i].get()]
    textbox.delete(1.0, "end")
    if False not in function_results:
        textbox.insert(1.0, "Ok")

#TEXTOBOX
textbox = tk.Text(root, width=33, height=10, font=('helvetic', 12))
textbox.pack()

#BUTTON
button = tk.Button(root, text="Ok", command=aaa)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your answer does not help me, because as mentioned in the question I will have to add dozens of other checkboxes and it would become complicated to create combinations with many checkboxes. I was looking for some more automatic solution. Thanks for getting back to me, but I wasn't looking for something that lists potential acceptable combinations.

Comment: How do you know which checkbuttons you don't want printing ok and which ones you do?

Comment: I don't want to print the ones that contain a wrong result, for example checkbox2 with 5 + 3 == 7 I don't want to print it. I wrote it in the question in the third point. This is just an example, obviously then I'll replace it with other code. Could you please help me? Thank you :)

Comment: Ah I think I get what you want now, working on modifying my solution for you

Comment: You are very kind. I would like to add another 20 or 30 checkboxes, so it would be very difficult and tiring to create so many combinations. I'm looking for something more automatic based on True and False. I'm waiting for your answer. Thank you