# Apply multiple selection functions to checkboxes (they are saved and loaded from the database)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, checkbox

I have an executable code that saves and loads checked or unchecked checkboxes in a database. This works correctly.

Each checkbox has functions that I talked about in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71148846/simple-problem-in-multiple-checkbox-selection-with-executable-example-is-there/71151300?noredirect=1#comment125773866_71151300) by kind user acw1668 (read the solution). I would like to apply the solution to my code of this question. You can take a cue from the response code of the user who solved the problem of multiple selection of checkboxes based on True or False. I would like to apply the solution of the other question of the link, to this complete code of mine that I report in this new question, because in addition the code of this new question has the saving and loading of checkboxes.

What I want? I would like that when you click on the Print button, "Ok" is printed in the textbox based on the multiple selection of the checkboxes and their function. If a checkbox returns False based on the function, then it does not print "ok". If a checkbox returns True based on the function, then it prints "ok" in the textbox. If all 3 checkboxes are selected, nothing is printed because among them there is checkbox2 which resist False. If, for example, checkboxes 1 and 3 are selected which are True, then "ok" is printed.

The code I want to add (that of the other question of link) whose purpose is to recognize the plurality of the multiple checkboxes selected is:

```
def clicked(flag, func):
    if flag:
        funclist.add(func)
    else:
        funclist.remove(func)

funclist = set()

def aaa():
    # if need to clear the text box, uncomment below line
    #textbox.delete("1.0", "end")
    if funclist and all(func() for func in funclist):
        textbox.insert("end", "Ok")
```

My code that saves and loads checkboxes, including GUI, is:

```
import sqlite3
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.messagebox
from tkinter import messagebox

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x500")
root.configure(bg='white')

chk_lst = []

#CHECKBOX
Checkbutton1 = IntVar()
Checkbutton2 = IntVar()
Checkbutton3 = IntVar() 

#CHECKBOX FUNCTION

def Button1_func():
    if 5 + 3 == 8:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def Button2_func():
    if 5 + 3 == 7:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def Button3_func():
    if 5 + 3 == 8:
        return True
    else:
        return False
    
Button1 = Checkbutton(root, text = "Checkbox 1", variable = Checkbutton1, onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height = 1,
                      bg="white", foreground='black', activebackground="white", command=Button1_func)
Button1.place(x=10, y=60)

Button2 = Checkbutton(root, text = "Checkbox 2", variable = Checkbutton2, onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height = 1,
                      bg="white", foreground='black', activebackground="white", command=Button2_func)
Button2.place(x=10, y=100)

Button3 = Checkbutton(root, text = "Checkbox 2", variable = Checkbutton3, onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height = 1,
                      bg="white", foreground='black', activebackground="white", command=Button3_func)
Button3.place(x=10, y=140)

chk_lst.extend([Checkbutton1,Checkbutton2,Checkbutton3])


#SAVE IN DATABASE
def save():
    conn = sqlite3.connect("value.db")
    c = conn.cursor()
    
    for idx,chk_btn in enumerate(chk_lst,start=1):
        c.execute(f'SELECT button1 FROM table1 WHERE id=?',(idx,))
        rec = c.fetchall()

        if rec:
            c.execute("UPDATE table1 SET Button1=? WHERE id=?;", (chk_btn.get(),idx))
        else:
            c.execute("INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (?,?,?);", (idx,chk_btn.get()))
        
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

    messagebox.showinfo("Saved successfully","Saved successfully")


#LOAD WHEN OPEN WINDOWS
def load():
    conn = sqlite3.connect("value.db")
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM table1")
    vals = c.fetchall()
    
    for val,chk_btn in zip(vals,chk_lst):
        chk_btn.set(val[1])
    
    conn.close()


#SAVE BUTTON
save = Button(root, text="Save", bg='#b40909', foreground='white', command= save)
save.place(x=10, y=10)

#PRINT BUTTON
button = tk.Button(root, text="Print", command= lambda: [aaa()])
button.place(x=100, y=10)

#TEXTOBOX
textbox = tk.Text(root, width=33, height=10, font=('helvetic', 12))
textbox.place(x=10, y=220)

load()

root.mainloop()
```

Simple database:

```
CREATE TABLE "table1" (
    "id"    INTEGER,
    "Button1"   TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY("id" AUTOINCREMENT)
);
```

Comment: Well, then, the command function for your print button needs do something like `if Button1_func() and not Button2_func() and Button3_func():` / `textbox.config(text='OK')` / `else:` / `textbox.config(text='')`.  There's no point in having those functions called for the checkboxes.

Comment: @Tim Roberts I know it. I wanted this, but then the code was corrected. In fact if you read more, you will see that user acw1668 has improved my code by solving the problem of the other question. Read the answer that solved the question (I also reported the code in my new question). With the link question solution code I get what I want. Okay that answer. Now I'd like to apply that code to my new question. can you help me? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need another list to store the function references as well:

```py
chk_lst = []
fn_list = []
```

Then update it like `chk_list`:

```py
chk_lst.extend([Checkbutton1, Checkbutton2, Checkbutton3])
fn_lst.extend([Button1_func, Button2_func, Button3_func])
```

Inside `load()`, you can update the *set* `funclist` based on the retrieved data from database:

```py
def load():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('value.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute('SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY id')
    vals = c.fetchall()

    for val, chk_btn, func in zip(vals, chk_lst, fn_lst):
        chk_btn.set(val[1])
        if val[1] == '1':
            funclist.add(func)

    conn.close()
```

---

Full example based on your code:

```py
import sqlite3
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("600x600")
root.configure(bg='white')

chk_lst = []
fn_lst = []
funclist = set()

Checkbutton1 = tk.IntVar()
Checkbutton2 = tk.IntVar()
Checkbutton3 = tk.IntVar()

#CHECKBOX'S FUNCTIONS
def Button1_func():
    if 5 + 3 == 8:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def Button2_func():
    if 5 + 3 == 7:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def Button3_func():
    if 5 + 3 == 8:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def clicked(flag, func):
    if flag:
        funclist.add(func)
    else:
        funclist.remove(func)


#CHECKBOX
Button1 = tk.Checkbutton(root, text = "Checkbox 1", variable = Checkbutton1, onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height = 1,
                         bg="white", foreground='black', activebackground="white",
                         command=lambda: clicked(Checkbutton1.get(), Button1_func))
Button1.place(x=10, y=36)

Button2 = tk.Checkbutton(root, text = "Checkbox 2", variable = Checkbutton2, onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height = 1,
                         bg="white", foreground='black', activebackground="white",
                         command=lambda: clicked(Checkbutton2.get(), Button2_func))
Button2.place(x=10, y=66)

Button3 = tk.Checkbutton(root, text = "Checkbox 3", variable = Checkbutton3, onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height = 1,
                         bg="white", foreground='black', activebackground="white",
                         command=lambda: clicked(Checkbutton3.get(), Button3_func))
Button3.place(x=10, y=146)

chk_lst.extend([Checkbutton1, Checkbutton2, Checkbutton3])
fn_lst.extend([Button1_func, Button2_func, Button3_func])


#SAVE IN DATABASE
def save():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('value.db')
    c = conn.cursor()

    for idx, chk_btn in enumerate(chk_lst, start=1):
        try:
            c.execute('INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (?, ?)', (idx, chk_btn.get()))
        except sqlite3.IntegrityError:
            c.execute('UPDATE table1 SET Button1 = ? WHERE id = ?', (chk_btn.get(), idx))

    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

    messagebox.showinfo('SAVE', 'Saved successfully')


#LOAD WHEN OPEN WINDOWS
def load():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('value.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute('SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY id')
    vals = c.fetchall()

    for val, chk_btn, func in zip(vals, chk_lst, fn_lst):
        chk_btn.set(val[1])
        if val[1] == '1':
            funclist.add(func)

    conn.close()


#BUTTON FUNCTION
def aaa():
    # if need to clear the text box, uncomment below line
    #textbox.delete("1.0", "end")
    if funclist and all(func() for func in funclist):
        textbox.insert("end", "Ok")


#SAVE BUTTON
save = tk.Button(root, text="Save", bg='#b40909', foreground='white', command= save)
save.place(x=10, y=10)

#TEXTOBOX
textbox = tk.Text(root, width=33, height=10, font=('helvetic', 12))
textbox.place(x=10, y=220)

#PRINT BUTTON
button = tk.Button(root, text="Print", command= lambda: [aaa()])
button.place(x=100, y=10)

load()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I thank you for the answer. I've been banging my head for hours now, I'm a bit confused at the moment. Can you show me the full code too please? I am having difficulties. So with the complete code the answer will also be useful for future readers. Thank you

Comment: @DragomirCro Added full example based on yours.

Comment: Thank you very much. You have been very kind and helpful in both questions. I had searched for something similar on StackOverflow, but found nothing. This question and the other question will also be very useful for future readers. Considering that it is very late at night here with me, can I put the green tick on you tomorrow? I want to check the code more carefully because now I'm tired. Even if you have some little doubts tomorrow. Don't worry I don't forget. This code is very important to me. Vote for the answer. We will talk tomorrow. Thank you. I will not forget, don't worry

Comment: I checked calmly. The code is fine. I get just what I want. You are great :) Thank you. However, I did not understand what flags and funcs are and what they are inside the clicked function. Can you briefly explain what they are? Thank you

Comment: `flag` and `func` are just argument names.  They are passed as the value of `CheckbuttonX.get()` and reference of `ButtonX_func` correspondingly inside those lambdas used in `command` option of those `Checkbutton` widgets.

Comment: I don't know if you have already read the comment I deleted.I have published a new question again(corrected and improved compared to the other one) and I would be happy to receive your little help,because it concerns the code you wrote me,with the textbox display added in another window.I also mentioned you.If you feel like helping me I would be happy,because being your code you can help me in no time,but if you don't feel like it,I understand it.Thanks anyway https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71179047/change-the-textox-output-by-changing-its-display-from-a-secondary-window-to-a-ma